# Kerberos ticket granting ticket

Tags: windows, server

Identify the two possible events that can trigger the Kerberos server to issue out a new "ticket granting ticket"? <---- This is a question I do not understand, can any expert help me with understand this and answer it

Comment: One of the responsibilities of a KDC is issuing ticket-granting tickets. There's more than one event/circumstance under which that will happen. Sounds like you need to describe under which such circumstances

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios where this happens:

1. During user authentication. User authenticates with a password or a certificate and in return they get a TGT.
2. User has a TGT and requests a renewal of that TGT. They provide the TGT and in return they get a TGT with future expiration dates.

One might argue that (2) is not strictly accurate because it's not a "new" TGT. In fact it's the original TGT, but just with the dates extended.

In practice the only time the KDC issues a "new" TGT is during (1). Everything else derives from that.

Comment: Thank you sir in assisting me with your knowledge, I'm grateful for that. Cheers!